# How can I mix nullable and not nullable T within a single class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm using C# 10 and VS2022, if that affects answers.

I'm trying to write a class to contain parameters with various constraints. The base type should be not nullable, as should some of the parameters (like default) while some of the other parameters need to be nullable (and I'll check they're not null as necessary). I can't find a way to mix the types in any fashion in the class.

I originally thought I could define T as notnull and then use T? with any properties I want nullable, while I can define the class/functions that way trying to call the code fails to compile.

```
    public class Parameter<T> where T : notnull {
        public T Value { get; set;}
        public T? Min { get; set; }

        public void Set(T? value_) 
        {
        }
    }

Parameter<int> parameter = new();
parameter.Set(null);
```

If I inspect Set via VS2022 in the class, it properly shows Set(T? value_) as the parameter, but if I inspect parameter.Set it shows Set(int value), and then refuses to compile the above usage with:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from int? to int
```

I considered defining nullable properties as T2 and allowing that to be null, but then I have the issue that I can't compare or assign T and T2, which would defeat the purpose.

Am I missing something stupid here or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can with a `struct` constraint. Can't you pass `int?` as an thr generic parameter instead though?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar you can but it will generate warning due to the constraint.

Comment: @GuruStron you mean the `notnull` one? I was assuming that would be removed.

Comment: Nullable reference and nullable value types are very different in terms of underlying compiler handling which at the moment results in such weird behaviour. Unless you are willing to restrict `T` to `struct` I'm afraid there is not much you can do.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I could remove the notnull constraint, but I need some of the parameters (not shown) to be not null. I suppose I might be able to remove notnull and then check the values at runtime, but that defeats the purpose of compile time checking for the fields, which is what I'm after.

Comment: @nlaak well, if you replaced it with `struct` as I was suggesting, it could never be null so... Or do you use reference types too?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar All of my usage (as implied above) will be value types (int, float, bool primarily). I don't see how struct will help anything, unless you're suggesting instead of using direct value types I'd need to define a struct with an int, struct with a float, etc and use those?

Comment: The types you're talking about would pass the struct constraint. You wouldn't need to create wrapper types.

Comment: How about something like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/XBr6vc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you stated in the comments:

> All of my usage (as implied above) will be value types (int, float, bool primarily)

Just use `struct` [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

> `where T : struct` - The type argument must be a non-nullable value type. For information about nullable value types, see [Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). Because all value types have an accessible parameterless constructor, the `struct` constraint implies the `new()` constraint and can't be combined with the `new()` constraint. You can't combine the `struct` constraint with the `unmanaged` constraint.

```
public class Parameter<T> where T : struct {
    public T Value { get; set;}
    public T? Min { get; set; }

    public void Set(T? value_) 
    {
    }
}
```

Which will allow `T?` to be resolved into [nullable value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) which will make `parameter.Set(null);` valid.

Comment: That does seem to be what I need, thanks for the explanation and answer

Comment: @nlaak as the quote from the documentation says - `struct` is a generic constraint representing all value types (not ideal naming, I can agree), not only custom ones.